# jquery select value in form input

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

I have a table like this:

[image]

I wanted when I select id_siswa it will exit nominal_iuran value in the form of input, but I have difficulty in that regard.

The following illustration zoom
[image]

and I use this coding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      jQuery(function($) {
        $('select[name=id_siswa]').on('change', function() {
          var name = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        $('input[name=nominal_iuran]').val(name);
      });
    });
 </script>
```

Please help me Master

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: Where does this table live?

Comment: I want to value that comes out nominal_iurannot selected

Comment: I wanted when I select id_siswa it will exit nominal_iuran value in the form of input, please help me

Comment: *"I have a table"* - Do you mean an HTML `<table>`, or a database table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how you are loading your data in the first place but:

If you didn't want to use ajax then when you first load the page with data from the database, you could add a data-attribute to the option and then grab that for the value instead of the name.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('select[name=id_siswa]').on('change', function() {
    var name = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    var otherValue = $(this).find('option:selected').attr("data-nominaliuran");
    console.log(otherValue);
    $('input[name=nominal_iuran]').val(otherValue);
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

If you didnt want to use ajax then when you first load the page with data from the database, you could add a data-attribute to the option and then grab that for the value instead of the name...<br>
<select name=id_siswa>
  <option value=test1 data-nominaliuran="60000">TEST1</option>
  <option value=test2 data-nominaliuran="200">TEST2</option>
  <option value=test3 data-nominaliuran="0">TEST3</option>
</select>
<br><br>NOMINAL_IURAN: <input name="nominal_iuran">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't query your table directly with jQuery (or JavaScript). You have to use a server side scripting language like PHP, Python, etc. to do that and then return the results to your page.

Comment: How do I master?
I have yet to find its logic

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing more about your environment. But if you don't know any of the server side scripting languages, you should go to [link]http://www.w3schools.com[/link] and learn PHP or Python.